# About mmap in multiprocess

Tags: c

For example ， there are one File（we Called it File-X）and two process（both mmap File-X in there program own space）。

A process ：
      char * pMem = mmap(File-X);
B process :
      char * pMem = mmap(File-x);

Question is :
When A-process edit pMem's value , How long will B-process detect it happened?
B-process will know it right away? or some cpu cycles?

Comment: Homework? What are your own initial thoughts?

Comment: i am chinese guy . my english is suck!

Comment: i know some variate in multi-thread . we need take care about cpu-cache(L1,L2) problem . so the same , i guess mmap make two different memory space in two process . do it would meet the same problem?

Comment: It depends upon how is `mmap` invoked, and on which processor. BTW, I am not sure the question makes sense (how exactly would you measure the delay)!

Comment: for example . In timestamp:1429384416.   A-process do this logic : ' *pMem = ''c" ' . And in the same moment (timestamp == 1429384416), can B-process know (* pMem == c) ?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory_002dmapped-I_002fO.html)...

> MAP_SHARED
>
> This specifies that writes to the region will be written back to the file. **Changes made will be shared immediately with other processes mmaping the same file.**

Therefore two memory maps within the same process will instantly see the results.

However, take note of the following paragraph, which states

> Note that actual writing may take place at any time. You need to use msync, described below, if it is important that other processes using conventional I/O get a consistent view of the file.

So although the changes will be available to other maps, they won't be available through conventional I/O until after the map is removed, or until you use `msync` to flush the changes to disk.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC memory mapped changes are picked up instantaneously. So process B will know straightaway.

Update:
Regarding your comment to the original post, memory mapping wouldn't create two copies, one for each process. It will create separate addresses inside address space of each process but each of those addresses will point to the shared memory location. That's why a change made by one process will be picked up immediately by the other process.

Comment: @phoneli not knowing a language should never be a barrier :)